# JPA Is there a way to do something like SELECT <field>, count(*) FROM <table> GROUP BY <field>

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jpql

I've been looking in the web for examples on the aggregates like count but it seems all of them are using the aggregate alone.

```
SELECT field, count(*) FROM table GROUP BY field

Should have something like:

field.value1, x1
field.value2, x2
....
```

I'm looking for a pure JPA answer for this one. If not I guess I can then do further queries just for the count part but that seems unefficient.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the question correctly but doesn't the following JPQL query do what you want:

```
SELECT p.name, count(p) from Product p group by p.name
```

You can retrieve the data like this:

List datos=(List)query.getResultList();

where Object[0] is the first field, Object[1] the second and so on.

Comment: Then how I retrieve the values from the result? It won't be a Product entity anymore?

Comment: See this [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936685/jpql-what-kind-of-objects-contains-a-result-list-when-querying-multiple-columns/2936713#2936713).

Comment: First object Object[0] will be of type Product, the second Object[1], will likely be of type "Integer"