# JPQL: What kind of objects contains a result list when querying multiple columns?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to do something which is easy as pie in PHP & Co:
SELECT COUNT(x) as numItems, AVG(y) as average, ... FROM Z

In PHP I would get a simple array like [{ numItems: 0, average: 0 }] which I could use like this:

```
echo "Number of Items: " . $result[0]['numItems'];
```

Usually in JPQL you only query single objects or single columns and get Lists types, for example `List<SomeEntity>` or `List<Long>`. But what do you get, when querying multiple columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get an `Object[]` (or a `List<Object[]>`). From the section **4.8.1 Result Type of the SELECT Clause** of the JPA 1.0 specification:

> The result type of the SELECT clause
>   is defined by the the result types of
>   the **select_expressions** contained in
>   it. When multiple **select_expressions**
>   are used in the SELECT clause, the
>   result of the query is of type
>   `Object[]`, and the elements in this
>   result correspond in order to the
>   order of their specification in the
>   SELECT clause and in type to the
>   result types of each of the
>   **select_expressions**.

If you want strong typing, you can use a constructor expression in the SELECT clause. From the section **4.8.2 Constructor Expressions in the SELECT Clause**:

> A constructor may be used in the
>   SELECT list to return one or more Java
>   instances. The specified class is **not
>   required to be an entity or to be
>   mapped to the database**. The
>   constructor name must be fully
>   qualified.
>
> If an entity class name is specified
>   in the SELECT NEW clause, the
>   resulting entity instances are in the
>   new state.
>
> ```
> SELECT NEW com.acme.example.CustomerDetails(c.id, c.status, o.count)
> FROM Customer c JOIN c.orders o
> WHERE o.count > 100
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Tuple and return a list of Tuple (`List<Tuple>`) which you can use as a list of Map.